# OOP PHP start level - It does not get the name. Does not display anything

Tags: php, oop, class-library

I just started (right now), to try to learn OOP PHP, and I can't believe I'm stuck already!

I can not find many tutorials with easy understand (I'm with one from killerphp for beginners but I think I might need a lower level...), the thing is...

The tutorial told me to create 2 files; index.php and class_lib.php:

### class_lib.php

```
<?php
class Person { //we define a class adding class before the name of the class
    //Properties of the person class
    var $name;
 }
```

### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Learning OOP PHP</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<?php include ("class_lib.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
     $stefan = new Person();
     $stefan->set_name("Stefan Grey");     
     echo "Stefan's full name is: " . $stefan->get_name();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone can explain me why it is not outputting "Stefan's full name is: Stefan Grey" ? In fact it doesn't display anything :/

And if anyone knows a tutorial for OOP for really dummies (I need basic explanations and easy, my comprehension is awful and I always need to read everything a thousand times before I can understand what they mean).

Thank you!!

Comment: Because you dont have getter and setter methods in your class?

Comment: :/ I haven't read anything about it yet :( do you know any tutorial for beginners? thank you

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

Go to the section : Defining Class Methods. This site does a good job of keeping things simple :)

Comment: no problems, was in the same boat not so long ago people here at SO are great so if you get stuck just ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mr. Alien mentioned earlier, you don't have *getter* and *setter* methods in your class.

> class_lib.php

```
<?php
class Person { //we define a class adding class before the name of the class
    //Properties of the person class
   var $name;
    function set_name($new_name) 
    {
        $this->gt_name = $new_name;
    } 
    function get_name() 
    {
            return $this->gt_name;
    } 
 }
 ?>
```

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Learning OOP PHP</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<?php include ("class_lib.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
     $stefan = new Person();
     $stefan->set_name("Stefan Grey");     
     echo "Stefan's full name is: " . $stefan->get_name();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the getters and setters. And for being an OOP programmer with PHP (wish more people were)

Comment: It's good practice to return an instance of the class in setter methods

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
     //initializing your class
 $stefan = new Person();

     //accessing "public function set_name($name)" in class
 $stefan->set_name("Stefan Grey");

     //accessing "public function get_name()" in class
 echo "Stefan's full name is: " . $stefan->get_name();
?>
```

you are accessing functions that are not defined in your class - maybe you should try adding these functions in your class - maybe like this:

```
<?php
 class Person {
     //we define a class adding class before the name of the class
     //Properties of the person class
     private $name = "";

     //this is a "setter-function", for setting values, that are not accessible from outside - so you have control over what is set
     public function set_name ($name)
     {
         if ($name != "Captain Jack Sparrow") {
             $this->name = $name;
         }
     }

     //this is a "getter-function", for getting values from non-public vars - you can also do manipulation here
     public function get_name ()
     {
         if ($this->name != "") { //if $this->name is not "" (Empty String),
             return $this->name; //return $this->name to your ->get_name() position
         } else { //else (if $this->name is "" (Empty String)
             return "Nemo"; //return a standard-value
         }
     }
 }
```

this is the oop-class-concept of "encapsulation" what you are looking for.

php has an awesome documentation in many languages - may you will hang out here for a while:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php